# Reuse js.rjs files in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views, rjs, renderpartial

i have an .js.rjs file, that must be used in many places.

How can i reuse it ?

For example, in my .js.rjs file i need something like this:

```
page << ( render "widely_used_stuff" )
```

where "widely_used_stuff" is a widely_used_stuff.js.rjs file, that contains the code, used in many places.

Also, i need to pass the variables to widely_used_stuff.js.rjs, like in this way:

```
page << ( render "widely_used_stuff", :locals => {:custom_script => my_script} )
```

### Update 1

I have tried following ways from .js.rjs file:

```
render "widely_used_stuff"
```

Rails complains on it, because it requires this "partial" to be "erb" partial

Following way:

```
render :file => "controller/widely_used_stuff.js.rjs"
```

Rails don't complains, but "widely_used_stuff.js.rjs" is not inserted to .js.rjs file, that called render. I have checked the XHR response.

I think, the problem is in the caller .js.rjs file, because it is not a erb...

Answer (score 2):

Hi have you tried `render "controller/widely_used_stuff.js.rjs"` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
page << render(:file => "common/index.js.rjs")
```

i hope could help .

Answer (score 1):

```
render :partial => 'view_directory/widely_used_stuff.js.rjs'
```